# T-SQL get values for specific group

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping

I have a table EmployeeContract similar like this:

| ContractId | EmployeeId | ValidFrom | ValidTo | Salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 5 | 2018-02-01 | 2019-06-31 | x |
| 25 | 8 | 2015-01-01 | 2099-12-31 | x |
| 50 | 5 | 2019-07-01 | 2021-05-31 | x |
| 52 | 6 | 2011-08-01 | 2021-12-31 | x |
| 72 | 8 | 2010-08-01 | 2014-12-31 | x |
| 52 | 6 | 2011-08-01 | 2021-12-31 | x |

Table includes history contracts in company for each employee. I need to get date when employees started work and last date of contract. Sometime records has duplicates.

For example, based on data from above:

| EmployeeId | ValidFrom | ValidTo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2018-02-01 | 2021-05-31 |
| 8 | 2010-08-01 | 2099-12-31 |
| 6 | 2011-08-01 | 2021-12-31 |

Base on this article: https://www.techcoil.com/blog/sql-statement-for-selecting-the-latest-record-in-each-group/

I prepared query like this:

```
select minv.*, maxv.maxvalidto from
    (select distinct con.[EmployeeId], mvt.maxvalidto 
    from [EmployeeContract] con
    join (select [EmployeeId], max(validto) as maxvalidto
        FROM [EmployeeContract]
        group by [EmployeeId]) mvt
    on con.[EmployeeId] = mvt.[EmployeeId] and mvt.maxvalidto = con.validto) maxv
join 
    (select distinct con.[EmployeeId], mvf.minvalidfrom
    from [EmployeeContract] con
    join (select [EmployeeId], min(validfrom) as minvalidfrom
        FROM [EmployeeContract]
        group by [EmployeeId]) mvf
    on con.[EmployeeId] = mvf.[EmployeeId] and mvf.minvalidfrom = con.validfrom) minv
on minv.[EmployeeId] = maxv.[EmployeeId]
order by 1
```

But I'm not satisfied, i think it's not easy to read, and probably optimize is poor. How can I do it better?

Comment: Why wouldn't just `MAX` and `MIN` work here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `group by`:

```
select employeeid, min(validfrom), max(validto)
from employeecontract
group by employeeid
```